# where will be nohup.out file created when shell script is executed by Java Runtime?

Tags: java, linux, unix, runtime, nohup

when I'm executing shell script through java Runtime.exec(), where do I find nohup.out file.

String command = "nohup ksh /home/xyz/script.ksh &";

Runtime rtime=Runtime.getRuntime();

rtime.exec(command);

Comment: `"&"` will not work.  That character is only understood by shells, and even though you are executing a shell, you are not executing your command in a shell when you use Runtime.exec.  The good news is, you don’t need `"&"`;  the process is already run in the background, even without that character.

Comment: so you mean to say Runtime.exec() neither generate nohup.out nor redirect nohup.out to some file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nohup` only writes the output to a file if it's connected to a terminal. This won't be the case when you invoke it through `exec`, so the output will be written to the sub-process's stdout (which you can get through `getInputStream`). No `nohup.out` will be created anywhere.

Comment: try {
 String command = "nohup ksh /home/xyz/script.ksh &";

         ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);

         final Process p=pb.start();

         BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

         String line;

         while((line=br.readLine())!=null){

               System.out.println(line);
         }
      } catch (Exception ex) {

         System.out.println(ex);

      }

Comment: String command = "nohup ksh /home/xyz/script.ksh &";

   ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(strCommand);

   builder.redirectOutput(new File("/home/heena/Desktop/megha/redirectoutput.log"));

   builder.redirectError(new File("/home/heena/Desktop/megha/redirectoutputerr.log"));

   Process p = builder.start();

Comment: Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
      Process process = runtime.exec(args);
      InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
      String line;
 
      System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:", 
          Arrays.toString(args));
 
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
      }